Programming UV5R with cable
I have 2 of the same model (new) UV5R's, 1 works fine programming and the other I get "Radio did not respond".  The cable is all the way inserted and I am following the same steps as with the other unit that I was able to send to radio perfectly. The screen acts like it reboots after a few seconds of clicking ok. What is going on?

Try unplugging the cable and plugging it back in. Make sure the baofeng is turned on, and if it is, turn it off and on again. Also, make sure that the baofeng is tuned to a channel with no activity.

Thank you for the reply.  I checked that and still the same action.
The screen looks like it does when first turned on where you are able to see every symbol - this happens a few seconds after clicking ok to upload or download from the radio.

I just fixed it by holding down the PTT button as I turn the unit on.  It works now and I am able to send and receive from CHIRP.
